# Finding same date and counting the object using Stream API

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, distinct-values

I need some help with the Stream API. I need to group a list of objects based on location and if location is same but date is different irrespective of time then increment count by 1.
I have provided below code for class with getters setters and data and expected output.

```
public class Event {
    String location;
    String date;
    String count; 
 
    public String getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(String count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Data for Event Class:

```
Event event = new Event();
        
event.setLocation("98.55.62.162");
event.setDate("09/17/2022 12:05:43 PM");
event.add(event);

event.setLocation("98.55.62.162");
event.setDate("09/16/2022 12:05:45 PM");
event.add(event);

event.setLocation("98.55.62.162");
event.setDate("09/16/2022 12:05:47 PM");
event.add(event);

event.setLocation("98.55.62.162");
event.setDate("09/15/2022 12:05:49 PM");
event.add(event);

event.setLocation("98.55.62.163");
event.setDate("09/17/2022 12:05:31 PM");
event.add(event);

event.setLocation("98.55.62.163");
event.setDate("09/16/2022 12:05:22 PM");
event.add(event);

event.setLocation("98.55.62.163");
event.setDate("09/16/2022 12:05:11 PM");
event.add(event);
```

I tried to make `Map<String, List<Event>>`

```
Map<String, List<Event>> eventMap = events.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getLocation()));
```

It's not working for me.
I need output like
Map<String,Integer> map where String is location and count is based on Date. If date is different then increment count by 1. Time is not important here.
I am not sure how to group them using stream API or for loop.

```
o/p: ["98.55.62.162":3 , "98.55.62.163":2]
```

Comment: By the way, [records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) would simplify your code. `record Event ( java.net.Inet4Address location , java.time.Instant when ) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on [the answer by Demian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73915511/10819573). I have made the following changes:

1. Use of `Locale.ENGLISH` with `DateTimeFormatter` which is not mandatory for your date-time values but is highly recommended because the date-time formatting/parsing API is `Locale`-sensitive.
2. Keeping the type of `Event#date` as `String` while I recommend you use `LocalDateTime` and parse the string date-time string while constructing `Event` objects, the way Demian has done in his answer. If you have separate values for day, month, year, hour, minute etc., you can use one of [`LocalDateTime#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-int-int-int-int-int-) methods to populate `Event#date`.
3. Use of `.map(e -> LocalDateTime.parse(e.getDate(), formatter).toLocalDate())`: In this mapping, I have first parsed `Event#date` into `LocalDateTime` and then extracted just the date part by using [`LocalDateTime#toLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toLocalDate--)

```java
List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

Event event = new Event();
event.setLocation("98.55.62.162");
event.setDate("09/17/2022 12:05:43 PM");
events.add(event);

...
...
...

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

Map<String, Long> eventMap = events
        .stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getLocation))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, v -> v.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .map(e -> LocalDateTime.parse(e.getDate(), formatter).toLocalDate())
                        .distinct()
                        .count()));

System.out.println(eventMap);
```

**Output**:

```
{98.55.62.163=2, 98.55.62.162=3}
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Both are valid answers. Provided by demian and Arvind Kumar. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but kind of tricky. Check this:

```java
Event event = new Event();
List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

event.setLocation("98.55.62.162");
event.setDate(LocalDate.parse("09/17/2022 12:05:43 PM", formatter));
events.add(event);

event = new Event();
event.setLocation("98.55.62.162");
event.setDate(LocalDate.parse("09/16/2022 12:05:45 PM", formatter));
events.add(event);

event = new Event();
event.setLocation("98.55.62.162");
event.setDate(LocalDate.parse("09/16/2022 12:05:47 PM", formatter));
events.add(event);

event = new Event();
event.setLocation("98.55.62.162");
event.setDate(LocalDate.parse("09/15/2022 12:05:49 PM", formatter));
events.add(event);

event = new Event();
event.setLocation("98.55.62.163");
event.setDate(LocalDate.parse("09/17/2022 12:05:31 PM", formatter));
events.add(event);

event = new Event();
event.setLocation("98.55.62.163");
event.setDate(LocalDate.parse("09/16/2022 12:05:22 PM", formatter));

events.add(event);

event = new Event();
event.setLocation("98.55.62.163");
event.setDate(LocalDate.parse("09/16/2022 12:05:11 PM", formatter));
events.add(event);

Map<String, Long> eventMap = events
        .stream()
        .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Event::getLocation)
        ).entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey, v -> v.getValue()
                        .stream()
                        .map(e -> e.getDate())
                        .distinct()
                        .count()));
```

Comment: I liked your idea of first grouping on `location` and then using the grouped `List` to derive the count. Do check some suggestions/improvements in the [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73916630/10819573).

Comment: Thank you. Both answers are accepted but I can only accept one so accepted one with LocalDateTIme though I am getting string for Date. thank you for your help.